# Hive SELECT DISTINCT and GROUP BY in a subquery

Tags: hadoop

I am running a query but I'm a little stuck on the concept of subqueries in HiveQL. I am new to Hive and I've done a lot of reading but I still can't get it to work.

So I have a big table with the fields I'm interested in being `created_date` and `size`. So I basically wan to run an aggregation of the sum of sizes of files created in a particular year and group by distinct year.

My current query:

```
SELECT year(created_date), SUM(size) FROM <tablename> GROUP BY created_date

2001    2654567
2001    231818 
2001    1978222 
2002    7625332 
2002    6272829 
2003    2733792
```

This gives me a list of all the years in the table and the sums of each year as above but I have duplicates of the year and this is where I need to do a subquery to `SELECT DISTINCT` year and the sum the total `size` too.

Any help will be superb please.

Comment: Why not `SELECT year(created_date), SUM(size) FROM <tablename> GROUP BY year(created_date)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try **GROUPING BY** the year, (since that is what you are selecting).

```
SELECT year(created_date), SUM(size) FROM <tablename> GROUP BY year(created_date)
```

Comment: Life saver! Thank you very much. I have been starring at this for a day and I couldn't spot this. Thanks again Joy

Comment: Yeah, it happens to all of us, glad I could be of help :)